# Run yii commands from shell script

Tags: php, git, yii, yii2, sh

I am trying to make a script which automaticly loads a project from a git repository. I run `exec()` from a php file with name of the shell script as an argument. The script looks something like this:

```
git pull
php yii migrate
```

The git command works well, but the yii command is totally ignored. I'm doing this from the root of the directory of the yii site, so it should work, but it doesn't.
How can I fix this?

Comment: what error you are getting? clarify your question? need more information.

Comment: Please provide the fill path to your yii,php file in your script and report back.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Yii version 1.x, you have to run your command from inside *protected* directory

```
cd protected
php yiic.php migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to run console application in Yii2, just use

```
yii <route> [--option1=value1 --option2=value2 ... argument1 argument2 ...]
```

Second: `yii migrate` is the defined console command to upgrade a database to its latest structure. So it probably does its work, but not that you want to.

Try to rename your console command.

Reference links to read:

[Guide: console commands](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html)

[Guide: migrations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html) (part with `yii migrate`).